# Using scanf for reading an unsigned char

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to use this code to read values between 0 to 255 (`unsigned char`).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char value;

    /* To read the numbers between 0 to 255 */
    printf("Please enter a number between 0 and 255 \n");
    scanf("%u",&value);
    printf("The value is %u \n",value);

    return 0;
}
```

I do get the following compiler warning as expected.

```
warning: format ‘%u’ expects type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned char *’
```

And this is my output for this program.

```
Please enter a number between 0 and 255
45
The value is 45 
Segmentation fault
```

I do get the segmentation fault while running this code.

**What is the best way to read `unsigned char` values using `scanf`?**

Comment: Actually `%hhu` for `unsigned char`.

Comment: @TJD. I don't want to read a char. I would like to read values between 0 to 255.

Comment: user1293997: you might want to write an answer and accept it (assuming @Joe is not interested in doing so). The only currently standing answer is quite incorrect.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `%u` specifier expects an integer which would cause undefined behavior when reading that into a `unsigned char`. You will need to use the `unsigned char` specifier `%hhu`.

Comment: This is really fine - but so sad gcc complains in C89/C90 mode - and further ms complains also: `%hhu` is not supported earlier than C99 as far as I know.

Comment: @BastianEbeling yes [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) `hh` is marked as yellow which means it has just been introduced since C99. I wonder how to read it in C89

Comment: There is an example below which is now deleted that uses [`getchar()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar).

Comment: why was that getchar() example deleted, off topic?

Answer (score 2):

For pre C99 I would consider writing an extra function for this
just alone to avoid that segmentation fault due to undefined behaviour of scanf.

Approach:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int my_scanf_to_uchar(unsigned char *puchar)
{
  int retval;
  unsigned int uiTemp;
  retval = scanf("%u", &uiTemp);
  if (retval == 1)   
  {
    if (uiTemp < 256) {
      *puchar = uiTemp;
    }
    else {
      retval = 0; //maybe better something like EINVAL
    }
  }
  return retval; 
}
```

Then replace `scanf("%u",` with `my_scanf_to_uchar(`

Hope this is not off topic as I still used `scanf` and not another function like `getchar` :)

Another approach (without extra function)

```
if (scanf("%u", &uiTemp) == 1 && uiTemp < 256) { value = uitemp; }
else {/* Do something for conversion error */}
```